# Could not commit JPA transaction while trying to do the registration in a spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using netbeans ide for Spring project. I am continuously getting the error could not commit jpa transaction on trying to do the registration (saving data on MySQL database). This is the error stack:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source)
at net.cdac.TMS.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:38)
at net.cdac.TMS.web.UserRegistrationController.registerUserAccount(UserRegistrationController.java:36)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
... 110 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.cdac.TMS.model.User cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (net.cdac.TMS.model.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @4df620d4; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getKeyOfOwner(CollectionType.java:446)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:166)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:53)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:59)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:183)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:229)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
... 111 more

The Role.java code:

```
package net.cdac.TMS.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Role() {

    }

    public Role(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The User.java code:

```
package net.cdac.TMS.model;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "uemailid"))
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "uname")
    private String uName;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "uemailid")
    private String uemailid;

    private String upassword;

    private String usecurityQ;

    private String usecurityA;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                            name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    public User() {

    }
    public User(String email, String password) {

    }

    public User(String Name, String email, String password, String securityQ, String securityA, Collection<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.uName = Name;
        this.uemailid = email;
        this.upassword = password;
        this.usecurityA = securityQ;
        this.usecurityA = securityA;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getUemailid() {
        return uemailid;
    }

    public void setUemailid(String uemailid) {
        this.uemailid = uemailid;
    }
    
    public String getuName() {
        return uName;
    }

    public void setuName(String uName) {
        this.uName = uName;
    }

    public String getUpassword() {
        return upassword;
    }

    public void setUpassword(String upassword) {
        this.upassword = upassword;
    }

    public String getUsecurityQ() {
        return usecurityQ;
    }

    public void setUsecurityQ(String usecurityQ) {
        this.usecurityQ = usecurityQ;
    }

    public String getUsecurityA() {
        return usecurityA;
    }

    public void setUsecurityA(String usecurityA) {
        this.usecurityA = usecurityA;
    }
    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

The login.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>User Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

            <div class="header-1">
                <img class="logo" src="../images/cdacW.png" alt="C-DAC">
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="form-center">
            <div class="center">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form th:action="@{/UserLogin}" method="post">
                    <!-- error message -->
                    <div th:if="${param.error}">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or
                            password.</div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- logout message -->
                    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out.</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="txt_field">
                        <input type="text" required>
                        <span></span>
                        <label>Email ID</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="txt_field">
                        <input type="password" required>
                        <span></span>
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pass"><a href="/" th:href="@{/forgotPasswordUser}">Forgot Password?</a></div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    <div class="signup_link">
                        Not a member? <a href="/" th:href="@{/registration}">Sign-Up</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The registeration.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header-1">
                <img class="logo" src="../images/cdacW.png" alt="C-DAC">
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- success message -->
        <div th:if="${param.success}">
            <div class="alert alert-info">You have successfully registered!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="registeration-form"> 
            <h1>Register here</h1> 
            <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
                <p>Full Name : </p>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder = "Full Name" th:field="*{uName}">  
                <p>Email id: </p>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder = "Email Id" th:field="*{uemail}">  
                <p>Password : </p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder = "Password" th:field="*{upassword}" required autofocus="autofocus">  
                <p>Photo: </p>
                <!--input type="image" name="image" placeholder = "your photo"-->
                <p>Security Question: </p>
                <label for="SecurityQ"> </label>

                <select name="securityq" id="securityq" th:field="*{usecurityQ}">
                    <option value="Your Favourite color ">Your Favourite color</option>
                    <option value="Your first pet's name">Your first pet's name</option>
                    <option value="Your mother's maiden name">Your mother's maiden name</option>
                    <option value="Your first school">Your first school</option>
                    <option value="Your Favourite food ">Your Favourite food</option>
                    <option value="The city you live in">The city you live in</option>
                </select>
                <p>Security Answer : </p>
                <input type="text" name="securityA" placeholder = "Your answer" th:field="*{usecurityA}">  
                <p><button type="submit">Register</button></p>

                <h5>Already have an account? </h5>
                <h4><a href="/" th:href="@{/UserLogin}"> Login</a></h4>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The UserRegisterationController.java code:

```
package net.cdac.TMS.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import net.cdac.TMS.service.UserService;
import net.cdac.TMS.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserRegistrationController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto() {
        return new UserRegistrationDto();
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm() {
        return "registration";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
        userService.save(registrationDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

The mainController.java code:

```
package net.cdac.TMS.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    
    @GetMapping("/UserLogin")
    public String login() {
        return "UserLogin";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "GuestHome";
    }
}
```

How to remove this error? What is the cause of this error? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Always check caused by for any exception you get. For you:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.cdac.TMS.model.User cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable
```

Have your `User` class implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and that should fix it.

Comment: How to do this? I am new to spring so I know little about it. @Chaosfire

Comment: @AnanyaTripathi Exactly as i wrote it - `Have your User class implement Serializable`

Comment: Thank you so much @Chaosfire. It did remove that error but now new error is caused:  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement;

Comment: @AnanyaTripathi The new error is entirely different question and should be posted as such. Follow the guidelines in the comment to the question on how to create minimal, reproducible example. With just partial exception message, best i can say is that you violate the constraint - the email is either null or duplicated. As for the cause of that i can only make wild guesses, which is hardly useful.